# How to format Date in DatePicker angular-material

Tags: angular-material, momentjs

I'm getting my Date from webAPI in BackEnd side and I get the value in ISO8601 format

```
fechaFin:Date;

fechaFin:2021-08-29T22:00:00;
```

But I need to show it in format dd-mm-yyyy, so, "29-08-2021"

So in my datepicker.html I have this

```
<input matInput 
    [matDatepicker]="picker" 
    (dateChange)="addEvent('change', $event)" 
    [(ngModel)]='date'
  >
```

Then in datepicker.ts

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
  parse: {
  dateInput: 'L',
},
display: {
 dateInput: 'L',
 monthYearLabel: 'MM YYYY',
 dateA11yLabel: 'L',
 monthYearA11yLabel: 'MM YYYY',
},
};

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cabecera',
  templateUrl: './cabecera.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cabecera.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  providers: [
  {
   provide: DateAdapter, 
   useClass: MomentDateAdapter, 
   deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE]
  },
 {
   provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, 
   useValue: MY_FORMATS
 },
```

],
})

An I See this

[image: calendar]

But I don't know how to see like this "29-08-2021"

In my control panel I have this

[image: region]

If I try this the same result

[image: rest]

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0):

Solved

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
 parse: {
dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
},
display: {
dateInput: 'DD-MM-YYYY',
monthYearLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
dateA11yLabel: 'L',
monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
},
};
```

Thanks